# How to add link to another page at the following code?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to setup a commercial html template that I bought but having some trouble changing a simple thing.
You can see the template here:
http://static.liveplace.gr/duk3r/green/index.html

I want to change the **portfolio** at the middle of the index page. Now when you press on the image or the title, it uses a **lightbox** to open the image in a bigger resolution. I want to keep that for the thumbnail, but when I click on the images titlebar, I want to go to **another html page**.

The html code of a single portfolio item of that section is:

```
<div class="3u 12u(mobile)">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="images/portfolio/fulls/pic01.jpg" class="image fit">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnails/pic01.jpg" alt="" title="Etiam Dolore">
            <span class="titlebar">Etiam Dolore</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tried to change it to this:

```
<div class="3u 12u(mobile)">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="images/portfolio/fulls/pic01.jpg" class="image fit">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnails/pic01.jpg" alt="" title="Etiam Dolore">
        </a>
        <span class="titlebar">
            <a href="otherpage.html">Etiam Dolore</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

but when I press on the title it still opens a blank lightbox (since there is no image in the link.

Any idea?

Edit1:

Checked the js files and could only find this reference to the portfolio items:

```
// Portfolio.
            var $portfolio = $('#portfolio');
            if ($portfolio.length > 0)
            {
                // Tabs
                    $portfolio.rotatorrr({
                        titlesSelector: '.titles li',
                        slidesSelector: '.slides li'
                    });

                // Thumbnails
                    var poptroxSettings;

                    if (skel.breakpoint('mobile').active)
                        poptroxSettings = {
                            overlayClass: 'poptrox-overlay skel-layers-fixed',
                            usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
                            usePopupCaption: false,
                            usePopupCloser: false,
                            usePopupEasyClose: true,
                            usePopupNav: false,
                            useBodyOverflow: false,
                            windowMargin: 10,
                            overlayOpacity: 0.85,
                            popupWidth: 0,
                            popupHeight: 0
                        };
                    else
                        poptroxSettings = {
                            overlayClass: 'poptrox-overlay skel-layers-fixed',
                            usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
                            usePopupCaption: true,
                            usePopupCloser: true,
                            usePopupEasyClose: false,
                            usePopupNav: true,
                            popupCloserText: ''
                        };

                    $portfolio.find('.slides li').poptrox(poptroxSettings);

            }
```

The whole css file can be found [here](http://static.liveplace.gr/duk3r/green/assets/css/main.css).

Comment: The lightbox is probably created with javascript. It's a wild guess since i dont know what selectors the javascript is using but you can try to change the name of the titlebar class (change corresponding css too). It helps a lot of you can show the initiation script of the lightbox.

Comment: @MarkBaijens added the css file and some js code that I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of Poptrox.

> Poptrox parses all anchors inside the element you call it on, even if they're nested in other stuff.

I think it should work if you change your html code to:

```
<div class="3u 12u(mobile)">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="poptroxSelector">
            <a href="images/portfolio/fulls/pic01.jpg" class="image fit">
                <img src="images/portfolio/thumbnails/pic01.jpg" alt="" title="Etiam Dolore">
            </a>
        </div>
        <span class="titlebar">
            <a href="otherpage.html">Etiam Dolore</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js code of the poptrox initiation to

```
$portfolio.find('.poptroxSelector').poptrox(poptroxSettings);
```

Comment: That was indeed the solution! Thanks a lot Mark! Now it's working as I wanted it to!